# LightGBM does not use all cores and RAM

Tags: amazon-ec2, lightgbm

I have an AWS instance with 16 cores and 128GB of RAM. Beside my LightGBM code, the system is mostly idle. However, LightGBM uses less than half of the cores most of the time and only about 8GB of RAM is used while about 10GB of virtual memory is used. Please see screenshot from the "top" command below:

[image]

How do I make it run more efficiently?

Comment: were you able to successfully install lightgbm with gpu on EC2 instance? I'm running into Cmake error all the time and have tried different different things but nothing's working.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same experience when running LightGBM in GPU mode. I haven't tried it in CPU mode only. I read using `max_bin` can help speed up, but had issues and yet to try out a lower value for `max_bin`.

Comment: were you able to successfully install lightgbm with gpu on EC2 instance? I'm running into Cmake error all the time and have tried different different things but nothing's working.